# Is it possible to make this method generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have a classes which implements some interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{  
    string GetKey();
    void SetData(List<int> data);
}

public class A : IMyInterface { .. }
public class B : IMyInterface { .. }
```

And I have a methods which gets the collections of this classes and make the same thing:

```
public void methodA(List<A> items)
{
    foreach(var item in items)
    {     
         // do something with A.GetKey();
         // do something with A.SetData();
    }
}

public void methodB(List<B> items)
{
    foreach(var item in items)
    {     
         // do something with B.GetKey();
         // do something with B.SetData();
    }
}
```

I would like to make this method generic:

```
public GenericMethod<T>(T items) where T: IEnumerable
{
    for(var item in items)
    {
        // how can I get the item.GetKey();
    }
}
```

How can I say to compiler that the elements of T:Inumerable implements IMyInterface and have the method GetKey() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
public void GenericMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    where T : IMyInterface
{
    for(var item in items)
    {
       // how can I get the item.GetKey();
    }
}
```

Although in current case you don't really need generics use tihs:

```
public void GenericMethod(IEnumerable<IMyInterface> items)
{
    for(var item in items)
    {
       // how can I get the item.GetKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Especially for last comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can just make your constraint: `where T: IEnumerable<IMyInterface>`

However you don't even need that, and could just make your parameter an `IEnumerable<T>`...

Or if you only need that `IMyInterface` you could just avoid generics completely and pass a `IEnumerable<IMyInterface>` parameter

By the way: your syntax is all wrong

[Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QjuOeT) with all three methods